# Parsing "Sat May 27 03:03:50 +0000 2023"

Tags: c#

I have tried the following code

```
string dateString = "Sat May 27 03:03:50 +0000 2023";
string format = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, format, null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out DateTime dateTime))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid date string");
}
```

and I have tried `string format = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy";`

Neither work
any ideas what and how i should parse this exact date string

Comment: That seems to work in net 7 are you using net framework? https://dotnetfiddle.net/uXqmR7

Comment: yes i am using .NET 7

Comment: That is because you are not specifying CultureInfo and your current culture is not en-US.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 4.7.2 or below you need to specify the culture. Here's how the line would look, when you use (as example) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture:   `DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out DateTime dateTime);`